# Extraction of features such as skills and responsibilities from job advertisements using python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, information-extraction

I am currently working on a project in information extraction from Job advertisements, we extracted the email addresses, telephone numbers, and addresses using regex but we are finding it difficult extracting features such as job title, name of the company, skills, and qualifications. Can anyone advise me on how we could extract them?

We found out that custom entities and custom dictionaries can be used as inputs to extract such attributes. When it comes to skills and responsibilities as they are sentences or paragraphs we are finding it difficult to extract them.
We have used spacy so far, is there a better package or methodology that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NER i.e. Named Entity Recognition for extracting different entities.

Refer this link for more details:
https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-with-nltk-and-spacy-8c4a7d88e7da

Comment: Thanks for your input, we tried Named entity recognition in Spacy, but the accuracy of the recognition is very low. Is there a method to use a custom dictionary as an input in spacy to recognize entities or build custom entities?

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-named-entity-recognition-using-spacy-7140ebbb3718 You can create cusom entities in Spacy